# Need help getting subcategories from database

Tags: php, sql, database, menu

I'm quite new to programming and I'm stuck on my latest challenge.
I'm trying to make a navigation menu and in case the category has a sub menu I'd like to display it on hover.
I'm working with a single table using navigation_id, navigation and parent_id (if 0 it's a main item, else it's a sub item)

So far I've only managed to show the main links

```
<?php
// Connected to database

public function getNav() {
        $query = $this->db->prepare("
            SELECT navigation,navigation_id
            FROM navigation
            WHERE parent_id = 0
        ");

        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

?>
```

The HTML part:

```
<ul class="navigation">
<?php
    foreach($navigation as $mainNav) {
        echo '
            <li>
                <a href="">'.$mainNav["navigation"].'</a> 
            </li>
        ';  
    }
?>
    </ul>
```

I'm really confused on how to get the subcategory items, if anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to query in your table using parent_id. Modifying your code:

```
<?php
// Connected to database

public function getNav($parent_id=0) {
    $query = $this->db->prepare("
        SELECT navigation,navigation_id
        FROM navigation
        WHERE parent_id = $parent_id
    ");

    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

You have to call getNav function with parameter id of that menu item for each main or top level menu.